# How to insert/retrieve images from a record in sugarcrm using REST API

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm

How to insert and retrieve images from a record in suitecrm. I use the following procedure, but no images gets uploaded. I see no_image in the detail view.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('1436568236500.jpg');
$set_entry_list_parameters = array(
    'session' => $login_result->id,
    'module_name' => 'WBUR_Vehicle',
    'name_value_list' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'value' => '376e1f17-d797-b629-92cc-558f28228524'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'front_left_image_c',
            'value' => base64_encode($contents)
        )
    )
);
$get_entry_list_result = call('set_entry', $set_entry_list_parameters, $url);
```

Also, how do I retrieve the images?